# How to count members of a distribution list which is not in Contacts folder using vba

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to create a vba tool in excel that will step through items in my Outlook sent box to calculate the size of each item and the number of recipients.
I hit a problem when a recipient is actually a distribution list. My code counts the distribution list as one recipient whereas I need it to count the members in the list.
I have found code which looks as if it would count members, but only if the distribution list is in the Contacts Folder.
However, in my organisation, all of our distribution lists are kept in a separate Address List outside of the Contacts folder.
Is there a way that I can lookup the number of members based on the distribution List name using vba?
Thanks in advance.

Update:
Thanks for the responses. My first attempt used the "AnalyseSentItems" (below) sub to loop through items and recipients and then called the "CountofRecipients" function to try to calculate total recipients.
I get the "Object Variable or With block not set" error at "AddressEntry.Members.Count".

```
Sub AnalyseSentItems()

'The code will loop through items in Sent Items created within the past n number of days
'and calculate the total size of items sent by multiplying the size of each item by the number of recipients

Dim oLItem As Object
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim RECP As Recipient, CntRecp As Integer, i As Integer
Dim DateSEnt As Date
Dim NoOfDays As Integer 'Number of days to look back on in Sent box
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objNS As Outlook.Namespace ': Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Dim Emailcnt As Integer, TotSize As Long
Dim innerDistListFound As Boolean

TotSize = 0
Emailcnt = 0

Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)

NoOfDays = 2

For Each oLItem In olFolder.Items
    CntRecp = 0
    If oLItem.CreationTime > DateAdd("d", -2, Date) Then
    'Calculate total number of recipients
    For Each RECP In oLItem.Recipients
        CntRecp = CntRecp + CountOfRecipients(RECP)
    Next
        Emailcnt = Emailcnt + CntRecp
        TotSize = TotSize + oLItem.Size * oLItem.Recipients.Count
    End If

Next oLItem
 
Debug.Print "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" _
        & vbCrLf & "Total Messages: " & Emailcnt & vbCrLf & "Total Size: " & TotSize _
        & vbCrLf & "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"

End Sub

 

Function CountOfRecipients(RECP As Recipient) As Integer
Select Case RECP.AddressEntry.DisplayType
Case Is = 5, 1 'Displaytype is Exchange or Private Dist List
    CountOfRecipients = RECP.AddressEntry.Members.Count
Case Else
    CountOfRecipients = 1
End Select

End Function
```

My second unsuccessful attempt used the "MemberCount" function below, passing in a Distribution List name.
This fails with "The Attempted Operation Failed. An object could not be found".
I presume this is because the Distribution List is not in OLFolderContacts. (It is visible in my "Global Address List").

```
Function MemberCount(DistListName As String) As Integer

Dim olApplication As Object
Dim olNamespace As Object
Dim olContactFolder As Object
Dim olDistListItem As Object

Const olFolderContacts As Long = 10

Set olApplication = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olNamespace = olApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olContactFolder = olNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
Set olDistListItem = olContactFolder.Items(DistListName)

MemberCount = olDistListItem.MemberCount

Set olApplication = Nothing
Set olNamespace = Nothing
Set olContactFolder = Nothing
Set olDistListItem = Nothing

End Function
```

All guidance gratefully received.

Comment: Please edit to show a [MCVE].

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

When processing the recipients, check `Recipient.AddressEntry.Members`. If not null (meaning it is a DL), check  the `Members.Count` property. You can also process each address entry in the `Members` collection recursively, in case of DLs containing other DLs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [AddressEntry.DisplayType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.addressentry.displaytype) property which returns a constant belonging to the [OlDisplayType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.oldisplaytype) enumeration that describes the nature of the `AddressEntry`. So, if you deal with a distribution list, you can try to access the [AddressEntry.Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.addressentry.members?view=outlook-pia) property. For example, here is the sample VBA code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DLExpand()

Dim currItem As MailItem
Dim recips As Recipients
 
Dim innerDistListFound As Boolean
 
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Set currItem = ActiveInspector.currentItem
innerDistListFound = True

Do Until innerDistListFound = False
 
    Set recips = currItem.Recipients
    innerDistListFound = False
    
    If recips.count = 0 Then GoTo ExitRoutine
 
    For j = recips.count To 1 Step -1
    
        'Debug.Print recips(j)
        
        If recips(j).AddressEntry.DisplayType <> olUser Then
        
            ' Expand the dist list
            For i = 1 To recips(j).AddressEntry.Members.count
            
                If recips(j).AddressEntry.Members.Item(i).DisplayType = olUser Then
                    currItem.Recipients.Add (recips(j).AddressEntry.Members.Item(i).Address)
                Else
                    currItem.Recipients.Add (recips(j).AddressEntry.Members.Item(i).Name)
                    innerDistListFound = True
                    'Debug.Print " innerDistListFound: " & innerDistListFound
                End If
                
                Debug.Print "- " & recips(j).AddressEntry.Members.Item(i).Name
        
            Next
    
            recips(j).Delete
            recips.ResolveAll
            DoEvents
       
        End If
 
    Next j
 
    recips.ResolveAll

Loop

ExitRoutine:
    Set currItem = Nothing
    Set recips = Nothing

'Debug.Print "Done."

End Sub
```